# I don't understand

Tags: docker, image, server, containers, port

Error Event [4746ca82-baf7-42c9-96dd-a3aca838a8c3]: environment/docker: failed to start container: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 2915535b-1c3f-4b4e-9446-54b0655cf27e (1e89c61e2fc2c53ef925cb7d21eb8ae52d4aa153141df281e49dcae03db1373a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 #ip:port: bind: cannot assign requested address

Pulling Docker container image, this could take a few minutes to complete...

this will start a game server

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is hard to answer without information on what you're trying to accomplish. Please edit your question and add information such as the command you're running and your Dockerfile, if you have one. Ideally, add enough information that we can reproduce the error on our own machines.